# Python - Recuperar/Mostrar data de una base de datos a FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, html, python, json, fullcalendar

tengo este view donde en la funcion def ObtenerTipoCambio hay dos campos: a.t_stdt (Fecha de efectividad, es decir la fecha donde registraron el tipo de cambio en el sistema) y a.t_rate (el tipo de cambio)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import static.library.general as general
from . import views

def tipoCambio(request):

    ambn = str(request.session["ambn"])
    ncmp = str(request.session["ncmp"])
    usua = str(request.session["usua"])
    
    lsel = request.session["lsel"]
    lsse = request.session["lsse"]
    dtgn = request.session["dtgn"]

    tpcb = ObtenerTipoCambio(ambn, ncmp)   

    return render(request, 'TipoCambio.html', {'lsel':lsel, 'lsse':lsse, 'dtgn':dtgn, 'tpcb':tpcb})

def ObtenerTipoCambio(ambn, ncmp):

    tpcb = []    
    
    query = ("SELECT   a.t_bcur, "
            "          a.t_ccur, "
            "          a.t_rtyp, "
            "          a.t_stdt, "  --Fecha de efectividad
            "          a.t_rate "   --Tipo de cambio         
            "FROM      " + ambn + "tcmcs008" + ncmp + " a " 
            "WHERE     a.t_bcur = 'PEN' and a.t_rtyp = 'TCT' and a.t_ccur = 'USD' and a.t_rapr = '1'"           
            "ORDER BY  a.t_stdt DESC ")
        
    conn = general.conexion()

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        tpcb.append({"bcur": row[0], 
                     "ccur": row[1], 
                     "rtyp": row[2], 
                     "stdt": row[3], 
                     "rate": row[4],
                     "title": f'TC: {row[4]}',
                     "start": row[3].isoformat(),
                     "allDay": True                     
                     })
    cursor.close()   

    conn.close()    
   
    return tpcb
```

En mi html llamado TipoCambio.html coloque un recorrido {% for obtc in tpcb %} donde coloque la fecha efectividad (stdt) y el tipo de cambio (rate)

```
{% extends 'masterPage.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<section class="content">
    
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dist/css/adminlte.min.css' %}">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/dist/css/adminlte.min.css' %}">   

  <script src="{% static 'plugins/fullcalendar/main.js' %}"></script> 
  <script src="{% static 'plugins/moment/moment.min.js' %}"></script>

  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.9/index.global.min.js'></script>   
    
  <div class="invoice p-3 mb-3">        
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">  
          <div class="col-6">
              <h4>
              <i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Tipo de Cambio                    
              </h4>            
          </div>             
      </div> 
  </div>        

  <tbody>
    {% for obtc in tpcb %} 
        <tr class="odd">    
            <td>{{ obtc.stdt|date:"Y-m-d"}}</td>          
            <td>{{ obtc.rate}}</td>                                                         
        </tr>   
    {% endfor %}  
  </tbody>   
     
  <body>    
    <div style="max-width: 1000px; margin: auto" id='calendar'></div>      
  </body>      

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        locale: 'es', 
        buttonText: {
          today: 'Hoy' 
        },        
      });
      calendar.render();
    });
  </script>

</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Así tengo mi base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito ayuda es que según la fecha de efectividad (t_stdt) se coloque el tipo de cambio (t_rate) en el FULLCALENDAR, por ejemplo: Si tengo una fecha del 06/11/2023 con el tipo de cambio 3.75, este me lo debe enseñar en el calendario, solo verlo como tipo consulta, esto debería aplicar para las fechas de anteriores meses. De antemano muchas gracias